# Invalid Servicestack license

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

I get this runtime exception when trying to use my new license.

```
This license is invalid. Please see servicestack.net or contact team@servicestack.net for more details. The id for this license is '[MyLicenseNumber]'
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I have tried both ways (app.config/code) of registering the license. The application is a console app using the Servicestack.Redis nuget package.

Of course the license is a Servicestack.Redis license and of course the team@servicestack.net have been contacted without reply.

Comment: Could we have some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by Updating the servicestack nuget packages.

I'm not sure why that solved my issue because the new version was not a major update (4.0.5 -> 4.0.15). Perhaps it was due to a version mismatch. One of my library projects used version 4.0.12.

I got a reply from team@servicestack.net which confirmed correctness of my usage of the code and the code itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you have followed the examples provided [Subscription section](https://servicestack.net/account/subscription) of the ServiceStack.net website and it is not working then you will need to wait for your reply from team@servicestack.net, as there must be an issue with the code itself.

Things to note if you are using a console app:

- You would need to include an `app.config` not a `web.config` to configure it from settings file.
- To configure from code, you need to run `ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense` before initialising the AppHost i.e. before `appHost.Init();`

Web.config / App.config:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="servicestack:license" value="XXXX-TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdC4gUHJvaW4gY29udmFsbGlzIHRyaXN0aXF1ZSBlcm9zIG5lYyBsYWNpbmlhLiBJbnRlZ2VyIHNlZCBqdXN0byBldSBhbnRlIHRpbmNpZHVudCBjb25zZWN0ZXR1ci4gU3VzcGVuZGlzc2UgZ3JhdmlkYSBk" />
</appSettings>
```

In code self hosted console application:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense(@"XXXX-TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdC4gUHJvaW4gY29udmFsbGlzIHRyaXN0aXF1ZSBlcm9zIG5lYyBsYWNpbmlhLiBJbnRlZ2VyIHNlZCBqdXN0byBldSBhbnRlIHRpbmNpZHVudCBjb25zZWN0ZXR1ci4gU3VzcGVuZGlzc2UgZ3JhdmlkYSBk");
    var appHost = new AppHost();
    appHost.Init();
    ...
}
```

In code ASP.NET application:

```cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense(@"XXXX-TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdC4gUHJvaW4gY29udmFsbGlzIHRyaXN0aXF1ZSBlcm9zIG5lYyBsYWNpbmlhLiBJbnRlZ2VyIHNlZCBqdXN0byBldSBhbnRlIHRpbmNpZHVudCBjb25zZWN0ZXR1ci4gU3VzcGVuZGlzc2UgZ3JhdmlkYSBk");
}
```

*The license code in the examples are fictitious, replace with your own real code*

---

Also note that if you base64 decode the license key after the prefix of `XXXX-` you should see the components of the key. If your key does not have data similar to this on decoding, the value may be damaged.

```
{
    Ref: XXXX,
    Name: Your Name,
    Type: Business,
    Hash: ZGhmc2tqaGZkamtuamt0aDNpdGtqZmtmaGtzamZuazQzaGtmam5za2pzZGhjaWtqbjQzdWhqa3Jl,
    Expiry: 2015-01-01
}
```